# Css stylesheet is throwing me a MIME error (works on other pages)

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I've literally just copy pasted another page that is working completely fine, but when i use the SAME code (that works fine on all other pages) i get this error on the new one i created.

```
2893:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/myleads/style/csspricing.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2893:13 GET http://localhost:8080/myleads/images/superleadslogo.png 404
2893:49 GET http://localhost:8080/myleads/images/logoinv.png 404
```

The page body is empty, but the problem occurs when i add the header and body

pic of the error:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Mer Information</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/csspricing.css">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white fixed-top" style="border-bottom: black; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #cdcdcd;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #cdcdcd; box-shadow:0px 1px 5px #cdcdcd;">
        <a href="/home" class="logoImage"><img alt="logo" src="images/superleadslogo.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon myToggler"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="margin: auto;">
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/home">HEM</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/priser">PRISER</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/produkt">PRODUKT</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/faq">GUIDER & FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/avtal">AVTAL & VILLKOR</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/svle">HÄMTA LEADS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-5"><a style="color:black;" class="nav-link" href="/myleads">MINA LEADS</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</head>

<body class="body">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<div th:replace="footer :: myfooter"></div>
</html>
```

Anyone know what is causing this? The code works perfectly fine on all other pages except this one...

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your code:

- All content of a webpage must be inside `body`. You have the navbar in the `head` section, which is not allowed.
- `<div th:replace="footer :: myfooter"></div>` is not allowed at that place, it must be inside `body` element.
- Unlike the error message you represented textually, the image you included states a different path:

> ```
> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/myleads/.style/csspricing.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.  
> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/myleads/style/csspricing.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
> ```

- Notice the difference between `.style` and `style`.
- Your console screenshot also suggests that your images have a pathing issue.

Suggestion: Please try and prefix all your paths with `./`. That will probably not fix the issues, but it's the paths that cause these problems, also most likely for the stylesheets, resulting in JSON being sent (probably an error message) by the server.

Use the network tab of your browser's developer tools to check for what the server actually sends.

Comment: Thank you for the answer connexo, i will try this sollution.

Comment: It worked!! i swapped <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css.css">to<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/css.css">

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because i was passing a pathvariable like this

```
@GetMapping("/myleads/{id}")
    public String showCompanyMore(@PathVariable(value="id") long id, Model model) throws SQLException {
        Optional<UserLeads> userlead = userLeadsRepo.findById(id);
        userlead.get().setLastSeen(returnDateWithTime());
        userLeadsService.save(userlead.get());
        model.addAttribute("company", getUserLeadSingleToTable(id));
        return "showmore";
    }
```

i swapped

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/css.css">
```

and the other linked files like javascript